# How can I implement a smart constructor for a struct with reference fields?

Tags: rust

## Background

I am doing the [wgpu tutorial](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu/).
In an early lesson, there is [the following code](https://github.com/sotrh/learn-wgpu/blob/master/code/beginner/tutorial3-pipeline/src/lib.rs#L161):

```rust
    let mut render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pass(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
        label: Some("Render Pass"),
        color_attachments: &[Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
            view: &view,
            resolve_target: None,
            ops: wgpu::Operations {
                load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(wgpu::Color {
                    r: 0.1,
                    g: 0.2,
                    b: 0.3,
                    a: 1.0,
                }),
                store: true,
            },
        })],
        depth_stencil_attachment: None,
    });
```

Since most of the `RenderPassDescriptor` struct is boilerplate, I would like to factor the creation of `RenderPassDescriptor` into another function. I tried to create the function like this:

```rust
pub fn make_render_pass_descriptor(view: &wgpu::TextureView, clear_color: wgpu::Color) -> wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
    wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
        label: Some("Render Pass"),
        color_attachments: &[
            Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                view: view,
                resolve_target: None,
                ops: wgpu::Operations {
                    load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(clear_color),
                    store: true,
                },
            })
        ],
        depth_stencil_attachment: None,
    }
}
```

Which would let me replace the original code with the following:

```rust
    let descriptor      = make_render_pass_descriptor(view, clear_color);
    let mut render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pass(&descriptor);
```

### The Problem

Unfortunately, since `color_attachments` is set to a temporary constant `&[...]`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
```

### Question

Ideally, I would like to tell the compiler to extend the lifetime of the temporary constant to the calling function's lifetime.
Is this possible? If not, what is an idiomatic way to factor out the creation of the `RenderPassDescriptor`?

Comment: This is not possible (without a macro), and I think the idiomatic way is just to leave it as-is, perhaps put the entire call in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wgpu` “descriptors” are basically just complex named arguments for a function. **Keep them together with their function calls,** and you won't have these borrowing problems:

```rust
pub fn begin_render_pass<'p>(
    encoder: &'p mut wgpu::CommandEncoder,
    view: &wgpu::TextureView,
    clear_color: wgpu::Color,
) -> wgpu::RenderPass<'p> {
    encoder.begin_render_pass(wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
        label: Some("Render Pass"),
        color_attachments: &[
            Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                view: view,
                resolve_target: None,
                ops: wgpu::Operations {
                    load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(clear_color),
                    store: true,
                },
            })
        ],
        depth_stencil_attachment: None,
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd been assuming the descriptors might be used for other purposes too, but your explanation makes a lot of sense- thanks!

Comment: @statusfailed I actually have on my todo list to contribute an explanation of just this to the descriptors’ documentation.